# Inno setup is not generating desktop icon

Tags: python-3.x, inno-setup

I'm using Inno setup to generate installer for my EXE package. My main EXE file is driven by a batch file. When i followed the below given scripts installer is creating shortcut. But the icon that i given in Inno script is not appearing as icon, instead default batch  icon is appearing. The application working very fine. thanks in advance.
My Inno Script file:

; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

```
#define MyAppName "cookie_crumbs_tableau"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0"
#define MyAppExeName "cookie_crumbs_tableau.bat"    
[Setup]
    ; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
    ; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
    ; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
    AppId={{EF731CE0-43E4-4C87-B33C-8F16C2529E77}
    AppName={#MyAppName}
    AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
    ;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
    AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
    AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
    AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
    AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
    DefaultDirName=C:\{#MyAppName}
    DisableDirPage=yes
    DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
    OutputDir=C:\Users\Cookie1\Desktop\EXEFINAL
    OutputBaseFilename=cookie_crumbs_tableau_setup
    ;SetupIconFile=C:\Dev\EXE\prod\crumbs_tableau\dist\cookie_crumbs_tableau\crumbs.ico
    SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Cookie5\Documents\Crumbs.ico
    Compression=lzma
    SolidCompression=yes

    [Languages]
    Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

    [Tasks]
    Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
    Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1


    [Files]
    Source: "C:\Dev\EXE\prod\crumbs_tableau\dist\cookie_crumbs_tableau\cookie_crumbs_tableau.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
    Source: "C:\Dev\EXE\prod\crumbs_tableau\dist\cookie_crumbs_tableau\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
    ;Source: "C:\Dev\EXE\prod\crumbs_tableau\dist\cookie_crumbs_tableau\cookie_crumbs_tableau.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
    ; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

    [Icons]
    Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
    Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
    Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

    [Run]
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: We need [mcve] - What is `MyAppExeName`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl please have a look now, script edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the bat icon as Innosetup is given "cookie_crumbs_tableau.bat" without IconFilename being used so it defaults to the bat icon. If you want a custom icon then use IconFilename to set an icon in your `[Icons]` section.

i.e.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\program.exe" 
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "{app}\program.exe"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; IconFilename: "{app}\program.exe"
```

Comment: Is the value of `IconFilename` to an existing file? Not working tells me little so please describe what you experience. My example of `"{app}\program.exe"` is just an example and you may not have that file. Windows/File explorer may also need to refresh as it may cache icons.

Comment: as i have mentioned in above question the batch script trigger the exe . Since constants in scripts are already defined , i think no need to add program.exe as u wrote.

Comment: This is all what i did modification :[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";  IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; IconFilename: "{app}\program.exe"

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are using `IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"`. This is still your batch script. The batch script triggers the exe you mention. Use the path to the exe as the value for `IconFilename` so its icon is used for the shortcut instead of the batch script. Instances of `IconFilename` values vary and I would not expect that.

Comment: You have a `crumbs.ico` mentioned in your script. If that is in `{app}` dir when installed and it is the icon you want for the shortcut, then use `IconFilename: "{app}\crumbs.ico"`.